# What does MULx operation in SNOW 3G correspond to?

Tags: stream-cipher, finite-field

According to the [spec](https://www.gsma.com/aboutus/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/snow3gspec.pdf), MULx operation is defined as  -

MULx maps 16 bits to 8 bits. Let V and c be 8-bit input values. Then MULx is defined:
If the leftmost (i.e. the most significant) bit of V equals 1, then
 MULx(V, c) = (V <<8 1) ⊕ c,
else
 MULx(V, c) = V <<8 1.
Example:
MULx(0x69,0x1B) = 0xC2
MULx(0x96,0x1B) = 0x2C ⊕ 0x1B = 0x37.

What does it really do ?

Answer (score 1):

It essentially is the value $02 \times V$ in the field $GF(2^8)$, and so MulxPOW(V, I, c) is essentially $02^i \times V$ in the field $GF(2^8)$, where $c$ specifies the *representation* used.

What is a representation: there are a lot of ways to map between 8 bit values and the members of the abstract $GF(2^8)$ field, and a number of those mappings are plausible (unless $GF(p)$, which has an obvious mapping between integers in the range $[0, p-1]$ and members of that field - so obvious that we typically ignore it).

What Snow does is use several different mappings (representations) for the various SBoxes, by specifying different $c$ values for the different sboxes.